# Lower idle power consumption: Ubuntu desktop or server?

Tags: power-management, idle

I'm planing to setup a Plex media server on either the desktop or server version of Ubuntu.

Since the device is going to run 24/7 but won't be actually used more than an hour a day, lowering the idle power consumption is crucial to me.

Is there a difference between desktop and server Ubuntu 18.04 in terms of how much power they use during idle state?

Comment: GUI uses processor cycles to operate; not having a GUI will use fewer cycles (thus less heat, fewer fan spins etc) so server would win unless you removed the DE from the desktop version.

Comment: Interesting, so the desktop version would actually use less power compared to the server version when I just deinstall the desktop package? Has anyone ever tried to measure the difference?

Comment: I think you'll find removing the DE from desktop, they'll be about the same; any difference being probably services enabled (running) on one over the  other. If both are tuned; they should be ~identical within the constraints of your hardware. The big difference is how installed (installer), what gets installed and what is enabled & runs.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24831781/1827088) you can find a good explanation about the differences between Desktop vs Server.